# Segfault in HTTPS request

Tags: c++, openssl, libcurl

I use CentOS 6.6 and I'm trying to do an HTTPS request with `curl_easy_perform(...)`. Everything works fine when doing non-HTTPS requests.

I set up all the fields like so:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, verb.c_str()); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeMemoryCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*) httpResponse);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

It is inside this last function call that I get the segfault.

Versions used in CentOS 6.6

```
libcurl (7.19.7)
openssl (1.0.1e-fips)
```

Does anybody know whether this versions are compatible or not? They are the latest in the CentOS 6 branch.

Comment: 1. It would be useful to have a complete example to try.

Comment: 2. Try running the program under gdb which might tell you where the failure is. And try running under valgrind which might give you some more information.

Comment: Hey! I had the same problem (I think). This helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975238/ssl-connection-error-even-when-verifypeer-verifyhost-disabled#24975649